# TensorFlow: numpy.repeat() alternative

Tags: tensorflow

I want to compare the predicted values `yp` from my neural network in a pairwise fashion, and so I was using (back in my old numpy implementation):

```
idx = np.repeat(np.arange(len(yp)), len(yp))
jdx = np.tile(np.arange(len(yp)), len(yp))
s = yp[[idx]] - yp[[jdx]]
```

This basically create a indexing mesh which I then use. `idx=[0,0,0,1,1,1,...]` while `jdx=[0,1,2,0,1,2...]`. I do not know if there is a simpler manner of doing it...

Anyhow, TensorFlow has a `tf.tile()`, but it seems to be lacking a `tf.repeat()`.

```
idx = np.repeat(np.arange(n), n)
v2 = v[idx]
```

And I get the error:

```
TypeError: Bad slice index [  0   0   0 ..., 215 215 215] of type <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

It also does not work to use a TensorFlow constant for the indexing:

```
idx = tf.constant(np.repeat(np.arange(n), n))
v2 = v[idx]
```

-

```
TypeError: Bad slice index Tensor("Const:0", shape=TensorShape([Dimension(46656)]), dtype=int64) of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

The idea is to convert my [RankNet](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cburges/papers/ICML_ranking.pdf) implementation to TensorFlow.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can achieve the effect of `np.repeat()` using a combination of [`tf.tile()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/tile) and [`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/reshape):

```
idx = tf.range(len(yp))
idx = tf.reshape(idx, [-1, 1])    # Convert to a len(yp) x 1 matrix.
idx = tf.tile(idx, [1, len(yp)])  # Create multiple columns.
idx = tf.reshape(idx, [-1])       # Convert back to a vector.
```

You can simply compute `jdx` using `tf.tile()`:

```
jdx = tf.range(len(yp))
jdx = tf.tile(jdx, [len(yp)])
```

For the indexing, you could try using [`tf.gather()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/gather) to extract non-contiguous slices from the `yp` tensor:

```
s = tf.gather(yp, idx) - tf.gather(yp, jdx)
```

Comment: Seems like there is a mistake in the code? I ran with `len(yp)==4` and the output of `idx` was `[0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3]` and not `[0,0,0,1,1,1,...]`.

Comment: Adding a `tf.transpose` call after tiling gets the correct output `[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3]`. The correct line is `idx = tf.transpose(tf.tile(idx, [len(yp), 1]))`?

Comment: Good catch - the answer actually gave an overly long-winded way to calculate `jdx`! I updated it to clarify how one might calculated `idx` and `jdx`.

Answer (score 7):

According to tf api [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/repeat_elements), `tf.keras.backend.repeat_elements()` does the same work with `np.repeat()` . For example,

```py
x = tf.constant([1, 3, 3, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
rep_x = tf.keras.backend.repeat_elements(x, 5, axis=0)
# result: [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

Comment: how to repeat a specific column, row or slice using tf.repeat()  e,g in numpy it is done like np.repeat([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], repeats = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1], axis=0) . 
This will repeat the value 3, two times and the result become [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]. but the same doesn't work for tf.repeat()

Answer (score 3):

Just for 1-d tensors, I've made this function

```
def tf_repeat(y,repeat_num):   
        return tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(y,axis=-1),[1,repeat_num]),[-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your question is so popular that people [refer it on TF tracker](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8246). Sadly the same function is not still implemented in TF.

You can implement it by combining [tf.tile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile), [tf.reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape), [tf.squeeze](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze). Here is a way to convert examples from [np.repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = [[1,2],[3,4]]
print np.repeat(3, 4)
print np.repeat(x, 2)
print np.repeat(x, 3, axis=1)

x = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4]])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(tf.tile([3], [4]))
    print sess.run(tf.squeeze(tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.reshape(x, (-1, 1)), (1, 2)), (1, -1))))
    print sess.run(tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.reshape(x, (-1, 1)), (1, 3)), (2, -1)))
```

In the last case where repeats are different for each element you most probably will need [loops](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop).

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anybody is interested for a 2D method to copy the matrices. I think this could work:

```
TF_obj = tf.zeros([128, 128])
tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(TF_obj, 2), [1, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import itertools    

x = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
N = 3 # number of repetition
K = x.shape[0] # for here 3

order = list(range(0, N*K, K))
order = [[x+i for x in order] for i in range(K)]
order = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(order))
x_rep = tf.gather(tf.tile(x, [N, 1]), order)
```

Results from:

```
   [0, 1],
   [2, 3],
   [4, 5]]
```

To:

```
  [[0, 1],
   [0, 1],
   [0, 1],
   [2, 3],
   [2, 3],
   [2, 3],
   [4, 5],
   [4, 5],
   [4, 5]]
```

If you want:

```
  [[0, 1],
   [2, 3],
   [4, 5],
   [0, 1],
   [2, 3],
   [4, 5],
   [0, 1],
   [2, 3],
   [4, 5]]
```

Simply use `tf.tile(x, [N, 1])`

Answer (score 2):

So I have found that tensorflow has one such method to repeat the elements of an array. The method `tf.keras.backend.repeat_elements` is what you are looking for. Anyone who comes at a later point of time can save lot of their efforts.  This [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/repeat_elements) offers an explanation to the method and specifically says

> Repeats the elements of a tensor along an axis, like np.repeat

I have included a very short example which proves that the elements are copied in the exact way as `np.repeat` would do.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.random.rand(2,2)
# print(x)  # uncomment this line to see the array's elements

y = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
y = tf.keras.backend.repeat_elements(x, rep=3, axis=0)
# print(y)  # uncomment this line to see the results
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate missing `tf.repeat` by `tf.stack`ing the value with itself:

```
value = np.arange(len(yp))  # what to repeat
repeat_count = len(yp)      # how many times
repeated = tf.stack ([value for i in range(repeat_count)], axis=1)
```

I advice using this only on small repeat counts.

Answer (score 0):

Though many clean and working solutions have been given, they seem to all be based on producing the set of indices from scratch each iteration.

While the cost to produce these node's isn't typically significant during training, it may be significant if using your model for inference.

Repeating tf.range (like your example) has come up a few times so I built the following function creator.  Given the maximum number of times something will be repeated and the maximum number of things that will need repeating, it returns a function which produces the same values as `np.repeat(np.arange(len(multiples)), multiples)`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def numpy_style_repeat_1d_creator(max_multiple=100, max_to_repeat=10000):
    board_num_lookup_ary = np.repeat(
        np.arange(max_to_repeat),
        np.full([max_to_repeat], max_multiple))
    board_num_lookup_ary = board_num_lookup_ary.reshape(max_to_repeat, max_multiple)

    def fn_to_return(multiples):
        board_num_lookup_tensor = tf.constant(board_num_lookup_ary, dtype=tf.int32)
        casted_multiples = tf.cast(multiples, dtype=tf.int32)
        padded_multiples = tf.pad(
            casted_multiples,
            [[0, max_to_repeat - tf.shape(multiples)[0]]])

        return tf.boolean_mask(
            board_num_lookup_tensor,
            tf.sequence_mask(padded_multiples, maxlen=max_multiple))

    return fn_to_return

#Here's an example of how it can be used
with tf.Session() as sess:
    repeater = numpy_style_repeat_1d_creator(5,4)
    multiples = tf.constant([4,1,3])

    repeated_values = repeater(multiples)
    print(sess.run(repeated_values))
```

The general idea is to store a repeated tensor and then mask it, but it may help to see it visually (this is for the example given above):

```
In the example above the following Tensor is produced:
[[0,0,0,0,0],
 [1,1,1,1,1],
 [2,2,2,2,2],
 [3,3,3,3,3]]

For multiples [4,1,3] it will collect the non-X values:
[[0,0,0,0,X],
 [1,X,X,X,X],
 [2,2,2,X,X],
 [X,X,X,X,X]]

resulting in:
[0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2]
```

tl;dr: To avoid producing the indices each time (can be costly), pre-repeat everything and then mask that tensor each time

Answer (score 0):

A [relatively fast](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/ragged/ragged_util.py#L113) implementation was recently added with `RaggedTensor` utilities from 1.13, but it's not a part of the officially exported API. You can still use it, but there's a chance it might disappear.

```py
from tensorflow.python.ops.ragged.ragged_util import repeat
```

From the source code:

```
# This op is intended to exactly match the semantics of numpy.repeat, with
# one exception: numpy.repeat has special (and somewhat non-intuitive) behavior
# when axis is not specified.  Rather than implement that special behavior, we
# simply make `axis` be a required argument.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 2.10 has implemented ***np.repeat*** feature.

```
tf.repeat([1, 2, 3], repeats=[3, 1, 2], axis=0)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(6,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int32)>
```