# Tensorflow equivalent of np.repeat() with non-uniform repeats?

Tags: tensorflow

Say I have

```
a = tf.range(5)
b = tf.convert_to_tensor([3,2,0,1,4])
```

Is there any way I could get

```
ans = array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4])
```

the way I would if I did `np.repeat(np.arange(5), [3,2,0,1,4])`?

I've tried `tf.tile(a,b)` and reshaping, the way it's mentioned in [TensorFlow: numpy.repeat() alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361467/tensorflow-numpy-repeat-alternative), but that gives me a Value error for shape rank.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361467/tensorflow-numpy-repeat-alternative

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, because the previous answer only handles the case where the counts are the same for each input value (whereas here they are different). There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8521) for this functionality in TensorFlow, and somebody has volunteered to work on it, but I don't know what the current status is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a combination of other operations available in Tensorflow.
This is tested on Tensorflow 0.12.0

```
import tensorflow as tf

def repeat(x):
    # get maximum repeat length in x
    maxlen = tf.reduce_max(x)

    # get the length of x
    xlen = tf.shape(x)[0]

    # create a range with the length of x
    rng = tf.range(xlen)

    # tile it to the maximum repeat length, it should be of shape [xlen, maxlen] now
    rng_tiled = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(rng, 1), tf.pack([1, maxlen]))

    # create a sequence mask using x
    # this will create a boolean matrix of shape [xlen, maxlen]
    # where result[i,j] is true if j < x[i].
    mask = tf.sequence_mask(x, maxlen)

    # mask the elements based on the sequence mask
    return tf.boolean_mask(rng_tiled, mask)


x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], 'x')
y = repeat(x)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(y, {x: [3,2,0,1,4]})
```

This should output: `array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4])`

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!