# How to create a new array of tensors from old one

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor `[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]` with dimension 9 X 1536. I need to create a new tensor which is like `[(a,b), (a,c), (a,d), (a,e),(a,f),(a,g), (a,h), (a,i)]` with dimension [8 x 2 x 1536]. How can I do it with tensorflow ?
I tried like this

```
x = tf.zeros((9x1536)) 
x_new = tf.stack([(x[0],x[1]),
                  (x[0], x[2]),
                  (x[0], x[3]),
                  (x[0], x[4]),
                  (x[0], x[5]),
                  (x[0], x[6]),
                  (x[0], x[7]),
                  (x[0], x[8])])
```

This seems to work but I would like to know if there is a better solution or approach which can be used instead of this

Comment: Is it a typo or is there a reason behind you not having `(a,f)` in the expected result?

Comment: Am sorry. Its a typo. I have edited it

Comment: This seems like the kind of question that would already be answered in the documentation for TensorFlow. While I am not an expert, you may want to take a look in the API docs (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/)

Comment: @EdOrsi This kind of tensor juggling is not in the documentation, but there are similar questions out there that can point him in the right direction (example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361467/tensorflow-numpy-repeat-alternative )

Comment: @AshwinRaju edited my answer to adapt to your data layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the desired output with a combination of `tf.concat`, `tf.tile` and `tf.expand_dims`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

_in = tf.constant(np.random.randint(0,10,(9,1536)))

tile_shape = [(_in.shape[0]-1).value] + [1]*len(_in.shape[1:].as_list())

_out = tf.concat([
    tf.expand_dims(
        tf.tile(
            [_in[0]],
            tile_shape
        )
        ,
        1),
    tf.expand_dims(_in[1:], 1)
    ],
    1
    )
```

`tf.tile` repeats the first element of `_in` creating a tensor of length `len(_in)-1` (I compute separately the shape of the tile because we want to tile only on the first dimension).

`tf.expand_dims` adds a dimension we can then concat on

Finally, `tf.concat` stitches together the two tensors giving the desired result.

**EDIT:** Rewrote to fit the OP's actual use-case with multidimensional tensors.

Comment: Working as expected :)