# TensorFlow train batches for multiple epochs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I don't understand how to run the result of tf.train.batch for multiple epochs. It runs out once of course and I don't know how to restart it.

- Maybe I can repeat it using `tile`, which is complicated [but described in full here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35367161/1339987).
- If I can redraw a batch each time that would be fine -- I would need `batch_size` random integers between 0 and num_examples. (My examples all sit in local RAM). I haven't found an easy way to get these random draws at once.
- *Ideally* there is a reshuffle too when the batch is repeated, but it makes more sense to me to run an epoch then reshuffle, etc., instead of join the training space to itself `num_epochs` size, then shuffle.

I think this is confusing because I'm not really building an input pipeline since my input fits in memory, but yet I still need to be building out batching, shuffling and multiple epochs which possibly requires more knowledge of input pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

`tf.train.batch` simply groups upstream samples into batches, and nothing more. It is meant to be used at the *end* of an input pipeline. Data and epochs are dealt with upstream.

For example, if your training data fits into a tensor, you could use [`tf.train.slice_input_producer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/slice_input_producer) to produce samples. This function has arguments for shuffling and epochs.