# Tensorflow numpy repeat

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I wish to repeat a particular number different number of times as shown below:

```
x = np.array([0,1,2])
np.repeat(x,[3,4,5])
>>> array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

(The 0 is repeated 3 times, 1, 4 times etc.).

This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35367161/2530674) seems to suggest that I can use a combination of `tf.tile` and `tf.reshape` to get the same effect. However, I believe this is only the case if the repetitions are a constant amount.

How can I get the same effect in Tensorflow?

edit1: there is no `tf.repeat` unfortunately.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Tensorflow uses numpy arrays. So you have the solution, right?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8246#issuecomment-286844231 maybe like that

Comment: This answer didn't help in this case unfortunately. I added this test case in that answer as well.

Comment: Are the original array and the number of repetitions both TF tensors (i.e. results of other TF operations) or is any of them known at graph construction time? Also, are your values always integers? Positive integers? (I know a general solution is best but there may be case-specific tricks to work around the missing feature...)

Answer (score 4):

This is a kind of "brute force" solution to the problem, simply tiling every value as many times as the largest number of repetitions and then picking the right elements:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Repeats across the first dimension
def tf_repeat(arr, repeats):
    arr = tf.expand_dims(arr, 1)
    max_repeats = tf.reduce_max(repeats)
    tile_repeats = tf.concat(
        [[1], [max_repeats], tf.ones([tf.rank(arr) - 2], dtype=tf.int32)], axis=0)
    arr_tiled = tf.tile(arr, tile_repeats)
    mask = tf.less(tf.range(max_repeats), tf.expand_dims(repeats, 1))
    result = tf.boolean_mask(arr_tiled, mask)
    return result

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(tf_repeat([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5])))
```

Output:

```
[0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2]
```