# is it possible to tile each row diffrent times by the given vector

Tags: python, tensorflow

With tensorflow, I have this tensors of rows like

```
[
   [0, 1, 2],
   [1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6]
]
```

and I have a list by which I want repeat above rows,

```
[ 3, 2, 1 ]
```

As a result, I want

```
[
   [0, 1, 2],
   [0, 1, 2],
   [0, 1, 2],
   [1, 2, 3],
   [1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6]
]
```

which means
I want `[0, 1, 2]` three times,
`[1, 2, 3]` twice,
`[4, 5, 6]` just once by following the `[3, 2, 1]` (which is my second argument.)

This is not a problem, if it is handled as a procedure.

### But I have no clue with tensorflow ops.

Suggested 'duplicated' question has a point.
The answer's idea was inspiring as well.
But I think there exist some needs to generalize the case and merge and carve the scattered solutions into one.
Let me add some solutions I have found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow numpy repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51490806/tensorflow-numpy-repeat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good answer.

[Tensorflow numpy repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51490806/tensorflow-numpy-repeat)

I found another clue from tensorflow contrib tree

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/59ecde3ecfc83aeb8ec0682e4e39bf0a234bbef8/tensorflow/contrib/training/python/training/resample.py#L32

which repeat a list of range([0,...,n]) of scalars to its own times.
0 to 0 times
1 to 1 times
2 to 2 times
...
n to n times

which looks too limited to use with itself.

But the `while_loop` of `control_flow_ops` looks very helpful.

```
with ops.name_scope(name, 'repeat_range', [counts]) as scope:
    counts = ops.convert_to_tensor(counts, name='counts')

    def cond(unused_output, i):
      return i < size

    def body(output, i):
      value = array_ops.fill(counts[i:i+1], i)
      return (output.write(i, value), i + 1)

    size = array_ops.shape(counts)[0]
    init_output_array = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(
        dtype=dtypes.int32, size=size, infer_shape=False)
    output_array, num_writes = control_flow_ops.while_loop(
        cond, body, loop_vars=[init_output_array, 0])

    return control_flow_ops.cond(
        num_writes > 0,
        output_array.concat,
        lambda: array_ops.zeros(shape=[0], dtype=dtypes.int32),
        name=scope)
```

So I exchange `array_ops.fill` in the `body` with

```
   tile_repeats = tf.concat([[counts[i]], tf.ones([tf.rank(rows) - 1], 
          dtype=tf.int32)], axis=0)
   value = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(rows[i], 0), tile_repeats)
```

And it workd.