# How to use tf.repeat() to replicate a specific column/row/slice?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361467/tensorflow-numpy-repeat-alternative) thread explains well the use of `tf.repeat()` as a tensorflow alternative to `np.repeat()`. one functionality which I was unable to figure out, in `np.repeat()`, a specific column/row/slice can be replicated by supplying the index. e.g.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
np.repeat(x, [1, 2], axis=0)
       # Answer will be -> array([[1, 2],
       #                          [3, 4],
       #                          [3, 4]])
```

is there any tensorflow alternative to this functionality of `np.repeat()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `repeats` parameter of `tf.repeat`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4]])
x = tf.repeat(x, repeats=[1, 2], axis=0)
print(x)
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [3 4]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32)
```

where you get the first row in the tensor once, and the second row twice.

Or you could use `tf.concat` with `tf.repeat`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4]])
x = tf.concat([x[:1], tf.repeat(x[1:], 2, axis=0)], axis=0)
print(x)
```

Tensorflow 1.14.0 solution:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([[1,2],[3,4]])
x = tf.concat([x[:1], tf.tile(x[1:], multiples=[2, 1])], axis=0)
print(x)
```

Comment: yes, you are right, unfortunately I have tf version 1.14.0, which dont have this function. I checked your answer on tf 2.x and it works fine.

Comment: yes tf.tile() exists in v1.14

Comment: Kindly check updated answer.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you for giving me a lead
```model = tf.concat([UpSampling2D(size = (2,1))(model[:,:1, :,:]),model[:,1:-1,:,:],UpSampling2D(size = (2,1))(model[:,-1:, :,:])], axis=1)```